# Invalid index (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)) when calling AddIns.Item[0]

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vsto, add-in

I am receiving **Invalid Index COM exception** when calling **`Excel.AddIns.Item[0]`**.

**`Excel.AddIns.Count`** works all right, which returns 4. But I just don't understand why **`Excel.AddIns.Item[0]`** fails to return the first **`Excel.AddIn`** object. The API doesn't seem to say too much about it either.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.addins.item

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most Office interop indexers are one-based, not zero-based (like the rest of the .NET Framework).

You need to access your first element using `Excel.AddIns.Item[1]`.

Subsequently, when looping, use a for loop similar to the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Excel.AddIns.Count; ++i)
```

Comment: What a tip that worth a million. Thanks so much. :)